# Excel remove data from 1 file to another

Tags: excel

I use acymailing to send newsletter.

I have my excel workbook "A" which contains all my users (20 000 people).
I import in Acymailing and sent a newsletter to 6500 people.
I get the list of these 6500 people in excel workbook. Let's call it "B".

Now I want to get the list of all the people who didn't receive my newsletter:
A - B, so at the end I should get 20 000 - 6500 = 13 500 people.

How can I do that?

Someone can help me please?

Comment: Do you set any kind of flag in the sheet A so you know which one gets a letter?

Comment: @Nino: did I solve your problem? If yes, please "accept" my answer by clicking the check symbol next to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In file A, if the email addresses are in column A and data begins in line 2, column titles in line1, add this formula to cell B2:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, [WorkbookB.xlsx]YourWorksheetName!A:A, 1, FALSE),"no")
```

Copy the formula down into all lines of workbook A, column B. Next, activate AutoFilter in line 1 (select first line then click the "filter" button on the "data" tab) and only select "no", unselect all other items. After you click ok, you'll have the list of people that you haven't previously contacted and you will see the number of filtered results in the status bar which will help you cross check the number of addresses (should be 13500).